# How to achieve low latency live-streaming with Wowza and Video.js

Tags: streaming, video.js, wowza

I've setup a Wowza streaming server and am serving Apple HLS video to a web page. I've read the articles on achieving low-latency live streaming and implemented all the details I can find. I have the Wowza server set to low-latency mode for the live stream.

The issue: The live video stream works for hours, but the latency is around 60-90 seconds behind real time. How do I get the latency from camera to web page down to 5 seconds or less?

Here is my html layout for video.js:

```
<div style="padding:5px;text-align:center;" preload="none">
    <video id=example-video width=720 height=405 class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls></video>
        <source src="http://1.2.3.4:1935/live/myStream/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
    </video>
</div>
```

Any insights on how to knock the latency down from 60 seconds to 5 or less would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you will need to customise the configuration as recommended below-

```
Audio AAC encoder – Bitrate:- 96 
Video H.264 encoder – Bitrate:- 800 
Keyframe Interval:- 2 second 
Tune:- Zero latency 
Buffer size:- 50 
FPS:- 30
```

Note: I have share based on the assumptions that you'r using FFMG or WBS to capture the live stream and supply that in RTMP format.